# What kinds of capacitors are they?

Tags: capacitor, identification

Does anyone knows what kinds of capacitors are they?
I searched everywhere, but I couldn't find anything.
Why there are these three "strings" on the top?
Why the capacitor value is not reported on the side as a "standard" capacitor?

[image: strange capacitors]

[image]

Comment: I hope they are inductors not capacitor, Even on the PC board Ref des is mentioned as L018 and L019 which represents an Inductor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment box "
I hope they are inductors not capacitor, Even on the PC board Ref des is mentioned as L018 and L019 which represents an Inductor"
 The specific name for these inductors are **Wide Band Chokes and bead** some of them can be find 
[Here](http://www.fastrongroup.com/series/44/findProducts)

Below are the PIC for these kind of inductors

[image]

Datasheet for the above part can be find [Here](http://www.fastrongroup.com/image-show/44/06H.pdf?type=Complete-DataSheet&productType=series)

Answer (score 2):

Those are not capacitors.  They are inductors.
The markings on the circuit board even indicate this.
Capacitors are marked as C and a number (C101,) but your parts are marked L019 and L018.
L is the usual marking for an inductor (coiL.)

Given the location and the form, they are probably there to prevent noise from the circuit from getting out on the power connections.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. I completely misunderstood your answer about my other topic. Does a resistance test with multimiter is a valid test to check if an inductor is bar or not?

Comment: It is doubtful that an inductor of that size has gone bad - you would usually see a burn mark if that were the case.  The capacitors I meant are more to the middle of the board.  The will have markings on the side that include the marking µF.

Comment: Yes I've already checked them but they seem fine. Since the board doesn't even turn on and the voltage on the switch button is very low I thought the problem was related to some components near the power cord. Anyway I recheck accurately every capacitor. Thanks.